# Merging hierarchy of dictionaries with same keys in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have several nested dictionary that contains dates on the first level, countries on the second level, and for each country, a list of numbers.

I want to merge all of the list which share the same keys, i.e, the same date and the same country to be merged together and form a final dictionary.

For instance, 3 of these dictionaries could look like:

```
a = {
2018-01-01: {'China': [1,3,5,7,8], 
             'Japan': [1,2,3,4,5]},
2018-02-01: {'China': [1,2,3,4,5], 
             'Spain': [1,2,3,4,5]}}

b = {2018-02-01: {'China': [2,4,6,8,10], 
                  'Germany': [1,3,6,9]}}

c = {2018-02-01: {'France': [1,2,3,4,5], 
                  'Spain': [2,3,1,4,5]}}
```

The merged list would be as follows:

```
merged_list = {
2018-01-01: {'China': [1,3,5,7,8], 
             'Japan': [1,2,3,4,5]}, 
2018-02-01: {'Spain': [1,2,3,4,5,2,3,1,4,5], 
             'China': [1,2,3,4,5,2,4,6,8,10], 
             'Germany': [1,3,6,9], 
             'France': [1,2,3,4,5]}}
```

I am not really sure how to go about this. I have tried to do the following, but it just merges on the dates and overwrites the values within each date:

```
merged_list = {**a, **b, **c}

returns 
{2018-01-01: {'China': [1,3,5,7,8], 'Japan': [1,2,3,4,5]},
2018-02-01: {'France': [1,2,3,4,5], 'Spain': [2,3,1,4,5]}}
```

Comment: Please include your attempt in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following recursive function would merge such a data structure:

```
def merge(*dcts):
    d = {}
    for key in set(k for dct in dcts for k in dct.keys()):
        try:
            d[key] = sum((dct.get(key, []) for dct in dcts), [])
        except TypeError:
            d[key] = merge(*(dct.get(key, {}) for dct in dcts))
    return d

>>> merge(a, b, c)
{'2018-01-01': {'China': [1, 3, 5, 7, 8], 
                'Japan': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
 '2018-02-01': {'China': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
                'France': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                'Germany': [1, 3, 6, 9],
                'Spain': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5]}}
```

Or, you can use a `collections.defaultdict` to make it more readable:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def merge(*dcts):
    d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
    for dct in dcts:
        for date in dct:
            for country in dct[date]:
                d[date][country] += dct[date][country]
    return d
```

Comment: Thank you! When trying the second alternative, I end up with empty lists.

Comment: Ah, minor typo: one `dct` instead of `d` fixed it ;-)